# How to make log4j log to different files on a per session basis in a Java web project?

Tags: java, servlets, log4j

I'm trying to debug an issue that is happening on a client site, it only happens on the client site so I can't test it in our lab environment, but the client is constantly using the system so the amount of data in the log files is enormous. Also if I switch the logging to Debug the sheer volume of log writes hitting a single file brings the server to it's knees.

How would I go about making my application log each http session to a different log file? To ease congestion to the file and to make the log file more readable?

Answer (score 2):

Disks tend to perform best when writing/read sequentially.  Writing to many files instead of one is more work for the disks as it has to jump between files.  I would not suggest using multiple files for performance reasons.  However it may be useful to be able to debug a limited number of sessions.

You can create a Logger for each session by including the session's id in the logger's name for that session. Then each session can be logged to a different file at a different log level.

However, you are likely to find that for this level of control you want you write to files yourself and control their behaviour more closely. e.g. writing to a GZIP file might reduce IO dramatically.

Comment: Is there an appender/configuration for log4j or Logback that allows you to write to a GZIP file?

Comment: You can write one, I don't know of an existing one.